# Recording video using Motion regardless of motion detection

Tags: video, motion

I'm trying to record a video using Motion, but it only records when a motion detected. Is there any option to use it as an ordinary video capture software?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. As stated [here](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigOptionOutputAll), we have the command 'output_all'; which makes the exact thing that I wanted -  allowing you to create continuous film:

> **output_all**
>
> - Type: Boolean
> - Range / Valid values: on, off
> - Default: off
> - [Option Topic](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigOptionOutputAll)
>
> Picture are saved continuously as if motion was detected all the time.
>
> This feature is not meant to be the normal mode of operation.
>   Especially not if you have the output_normal or output_motion features
>   enabled since it will keep on saving pictures on the disk and you will
>   soon run out of disk space. So be careful with this command.
>
> If your frame rate is 10 pictures per second motion will save 10 new
>   picture pr second until the disk is full.
>
> It does all the normal actions that are done when motion is detected.
>   It saves pictures on the harddisk, execute external scripts, etc as
>   fast as the frame rate of the camera. So it is probably a good idea to
>   run with a low framerate when using this feature and to not use
>   activate all the features that saves files on the disk.
>
> The idea of this feature is that you can turn the feature on and off
>   for a short period of time to test or to generate continuous mpeg
>   films when needed.

Comment: Forgot about this :) But it usually helps to have something to automatically delete old pictures if recording to disk as it will run out of disk space.

Comment: `output_all` has been changed to `emulate_motion` since version `3.4`.
Source: https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#Configuration_OptionsAlpha

Answer (score 2):

In the `motion.conf`, `output_all` was changed to `emulate_motion` in motion version 3.4. Using this records video along with live streaming.

Sources: user: [Kanchu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/87038/kanchu) |  site: [motion-project.github.io](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#Configuration_OptionsAlpha)

Answer (score 1):

if you need an application to do such matter please visit [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-motion-detection-webcam-ubuntu/). It is an `Ubuntu` tutorial but it works the same on `raspberry pi`
 But I highly Recommend you to try [Home surveillance and motion detection with the Raspberry Pi, Python, OpenCV, and Dropbox](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/01/home-surveillance-and-motion-detection-with-the-raspberry-pi-python-and-opencv/) tutorial. It is a greate post about `Raspberry Pi`, `Python` and `OpenCV`. it has great details and every body, with no `python` or `OpenCV` or even a `linux` knowledge can follow the steps and learn a lot.

Comment: NimaNr thank you for your effort, but I don't want to build a surveillance system. I just want to record video from a usb camera using Motion. Motion only records video when there is a motion in the scene; but, I want it to record non-stop video regardless of motion detection. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the file `/etc/motion/motion.conf` there is a setting for this, sorry I can't remember what it was I haven't used motion in about four months.

Comment: There is a command called 'output_all' which is explained as 'Picture are saved continuously as if motion was detected all the time.' in the website of Motion. However it can't even manage to make that for the pictures. The system works perfect with video; but, when I enable this option everything blows up. Motion keeps showing errors, deletes '/var/run/motion/' directory for no reason etc.

Comment: Ah, ok. It seems the problem wasn't about the command. After several reboots and creating motion folder under '/var/run/motion' I managed to make it record videos regardless of motion detection. Thank you Patrick for your help.